# Getting crash on iphone 5( OS- 8.2) ,when we install Application through ipa , but unable to get crash while debugging on the device

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, ipa, ios8.2

I'm getting crash on iPhone 5 (8.2) ,When i install through ipa but I'm unable to get any crash while debugging on the same device.Please help me how to fix this?.

Answer (score 0):

Start with looking at the console, to see what messages occur on the device.

Also, if you hook the device up to your development computer with a USB cable, you should be able in Xcode to look at the device logs to get crash reports and figure out where the crash is from.

Also check for TestFlight crash logs on Apple's servers (iTunes Connect)